# Get list of Enums from generic class

Tags: java, android, generics, enums

I have a class that is paramaterised with an extend of Enum.

```
public class MyClass<EnumType extends Enum> { 

  public MyClass(){
    Enum<?>[] enums = EnumType.getEnumConstants();
  }

}
```

The line:

```
Enum<?>[] enums = EnumType.getEnumConstants()
```

fails to compile with "can not resolve method".

How can I get to the base type and get the enums?

OTOH, if I do the following it works ok:

```
public void setEnumType(Class <? extends Enum> clazz){
   Enum<?>[] enums = clazz.getEnumConstants();
}
```

I can't pass this into the constructor as it is a custom view which is directly inserted in the parent.

Comment: Read about type erasure. Take a look at `EnumSet`, which has static factory methods accepting any `Enum`. Also, you should use `class MyClass<EnumType extends Enum<EnumType>>`

Comment: I know about type erasure and I assume that that is my problem. Was hoping there was a way around it. Using allOf runs into the similar problems to above. Complains about "expression expected" for the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Owing to erasure, you have to pass an instance of the enum class to the constructor:

```
public class MyClass<EnumType extends Enum<EnumType>> { 
                                       // ^ don't forget this    
  public MyClass(Class<EnumType> c){
    Enum<?>[] enums = c.getEnumConstants();
  }

}

MyClass<YourEnum> m = new MyClass<>(YourEnum.class);
```

Or, you could pass `YourEnum.values()` directly. The risk there is that a caller can pass any array, not necessarily one with all values, without duplicates, in the right order etc.